# Haskell, print modified list values with map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming

I have written the following code, which should take a list of values and print only the `values > average`, modifying them as `val - avg`.
For example `printModVal [9,0,6]` should print `4 1`, one element per line, using `System.IO` `print` function.

```html
import Data.List
import System.IO

printModVal :: [Float] -> IO ()
printModVal xs = ???
  where
    average = (foldr (+) 0 xs) / genericLength xs
    --use map here and print the values > average as value-average


modVal :: Float -> Float -> Float
modVal x y = x - y


mapVal  :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapVal f [] =  []
mapVal f (x:xs) =  f x : mapVal f xs
```

I would like to know how, at this point, how can I use `mapVal` (with `modVal` as mapping function) inside the function `printModVal`, in order to print the values > 0 (once modified by the mapping function).
Thank you.

Comment: Swap the arguments of `modVal`. Then it can be used as `(modVal average)` instead of `(\x -> modVal x average)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply a filter.

Either to the resulting list

```
printModVal xs = mapM_ print $ filter (> 0) (mapVal (\x -> modVal x average) xs)
  where
    average = (foldr (+) 0 xs) / genericLength xs
```

or to the incoming list

```
printModVal xs = mapM_ print $ mapVal (\x -> modVal x average) (filter (> average) xs)
  where
    average = (foldr (+) 0 xs) / genericLength xs
```

`map` does never change the length of the list it processes.
Any function with the signature `(a->b)->[a]->[b]` is very limited in what it can do due to parametricity.

Comment: This looks correct, but apparently `printModVal` needs to print the list on screen, rather than return it, since its return type is `IO ()`.

Comment: You are right. I'm just not used to functions doing so many things at once.

Comment: Indeed, separating computation from IO is very idiomatic in Haskell.

Comment: @MarvinSielenkemper thank you very much! Just one small thing: your suggestion prints all values in one line, how could it be modified in order to print one value per line?

Comment: @Pavz7 Well yeah, I noticed that, too ... I'm working on it.

Comment: hint: try `mapM_ print [1,2,3]`

Comment: That really helped, thank you @user2297560! I didn't know `mapM_`, I'll check it better.